# .htaccess mod_rewrite parameter to non existing subdir

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

I would like to extend my existing rewrite rules to rewrite a special url parameter to a non existing subdir.

something like this:

Real url is:

```
host.com/post.php?id=17&lang=pl
```

My existing rewrite:

```
host.com/somedescriptionstring-p-17.html?lang=pl
```

That ist achieved by this rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-(.*).html$ post.php?id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Now, I want to extend the rewrite to:

```
host.com/pl/somedescriptionstring-p-17.html
```

This, I want to use for two special language parameters: "pl" and "ru" - default parameter has to be "pl"

Someone can help me out, please?

Thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you will have two types of urls. One of the is in the form of http://example.com/lang/post1234.html and one is in the form of http://example.com/post1234.html. The second one doesn't have a language, and you want to default that to Polish. You'll need two rules for that. The first one will internally rewrite the one with language code to the real url. The other one will issue an external redirect to add "pl" to the url.

```
#This translates the fancy url internally
RewriteRule ^(pl|ru)/.*-p-([0-9]+)\.html$ /post.php?lang=$1&id=$2 [L]

#When there is a language parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=(pl|ru)
RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-([0-9]+)\.html$ /%1/$1-p-$2.html [R,L]

#default case
RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-([0-9]+)\.html$ /pl/$1-p-$2.html [R,L]
```

Change `R` to `R=301` after testing it works correctly.

Comment: this looks good. at least I don't get an 404 :-)

my original rewrite looks like this:

RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-(.*).html$ post.php?id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}

how to implement your suggest here? Thanks you!

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable, and at first glance that code does not match any url in the question. I am not sure what you want with the rewrite you already have.

Comment: I want to extend my RewriteRule (Code 3) to make Url at Code 2 look like Url at Code 4

Comment: somehow I don't get it done... could you please post with what lines of code I have to replace my rule at Code 3 please? Thank you very much

Comment: I've deleted some of my comments because it turns into a discussion. I've edited my answer a little bit since you changed the url's in the question completely. If you still can't get it to work you'll need to get some more reputation so we can discuss this in chat.